# How to find the largest objects in memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to have a table of 10 largest objects in memory, with size.

Equivalent function in R:
[Tricks to manage the available memory in an R session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session)

```
lsos()
#                          Type Size(MB)   Rows Columns
#d2                  data.table 157.8364 281444      74
#d                   data.table  62.2658 816078      11
```

Edit:
@ 9.0 Here is my attempt.

I have to use `globals()`, using `gc.get_objects()` makes my computer very slow. I am not sure `globals()` gives me what I want. 
[How to get the list of all initialized objects and function definitions alive in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458701/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-initialized-objects-and-function-definitions-alive-in)

```
def lsos(n=10):

    import pandas as pd
    import sys

    all_obj =globals()

    object_name = list(all_obj).copy()
    object_size = [sys.getsizeof(all_obj[x]) for x in object_name]

    d = pd.DataFrame(dict(name = object_name, size = object_size))
    d.sort_values(['size'], ascending=[0],inplace=True)

    return(d.head(n))


v  = list(range(1000))
v2 = list(range(10000))
v3 = list(range(100000))
v4 = v3
lsos()

    # name    size
# 0     v4  900112
# 22    v3  900112
# 1     v2   90112
# 17     v    9112
# 6     _i     395
# 14   _i1     395
# 19   _oh     288
# 24   Out     288
# 5    _i2     137
# 3   lsos     136
```

When I put the above function in say `abc.py` and run

```
import abc
abc.lsos()

           # name  size
# 8  __builtins__  6240
# 0          lsos   136
# 6      __file__   123
# 2    __cached__    97
# 1    __loader__    56
# 4      __spec__    56
# 5      __name__    54
# 3   __package__    49
# 7       __doc__    16
```

None of the large `v` appears.

Edit 2:
Because there's problem of accessing `globals()` in a module, I just pass `globals()` to the module, here is what I am using now:

```
#abc.py
def lsos(all_obj = globals(),n=10):

    import sys

    object_name = list(all_obj)
    object_size = [ round(sys.getsizeof(all_obj[x])/1024.0/1024.0,4) for x in object_name]
    object_id = [id(all_obj[x]) for x in object_name]

    d = [(a,b,c) for a,b,c in zip(object_name, object_size, object_id)]
    d.sort(key = lambda x:(x[1],x[2]), reverse=True)
    dprint = d[0:min(len(d), n)]

    #print formating
    name_width_max = max([len(x[0]) for x in dprint])
    print(("{:<" + str(name_width_max +2) + "}{:11}{}").format("name","size_Mb","id"))
    fmt = '{{:<{}}}'.format(name_width_max+2) +"  "+ "{: 5.4f}" +"  "+ "{:d}"
    for line in dprint:
        print( fmt.format(*line))

    return
```

Then it can be called by

```
import abc
abc.lsos(globals())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python)

Comment: @sam-pyt I think `sys.getsizeof()` does not get me LARGEST 10 objects.

Comment: but you can use it to find the largest 10 objects.

Comment: I found a great answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993626/list-memory-usage-in-ipython-and-jupyter

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simplest is to use [Pympler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pympler):

```
from operator import itemgetter

from pympler import tracker

mem = tracker.SummaryTracker()
print(sorted(mem.create_summary(), reverse=True, key=itemgetter(2))[:10])
```

Output:

```
[["<class 'float", 5004102, 120098448],
 ["<class 'list", 74279, 48527480],
 ["<class 'str", 214166, 23782488],
 ["<class 'dict", 14710, 7109016],
 ["<class 'code", 27702, 3991737],
 ["<class 'type", 3480, 3714520],
 ["<class 'jedi.parser.python.tree.Operator", 24936, 2393856],
 ["<class 'jedi.parser.python.tree.Name", 19965, 1916640],
 ["<class 'jedi.parser.python.tree.PythonNode", 23550, 1884000],
 ["<class 'int", 47671, 1382592]]
```

Of course, you can also create a pandas dataframe and work with this:

```
memory = pd.DataFrame(mem.create_summary(), columns=['object', 'number_of_objects', 'memory'])
memory['mem_per_object'] = memory['memory'] / memory['number_of_objects']
print(memory.sort_values('memory', ascending=False).head(10))
print(memory.sort_values('mem_per_object', ascending=False).head(10))
```

Output:

```
                                           object  number_of_objects     memory  mem_per_object
11                                  <class 'float            5004112  120098688       24.000000
42                                   <class 'list              74322   48532112      652.997928
2                                     <class 'str             214308   23797202      111.042061
44                                   <class 'dict              14738    7116184      482.845976
10                                   <class 'code              27702    3991737      144.095625
59                                   <class 'type               3480    3715616     1067.705747
9421     <class 'jedi.parser.python.tree.Operator              24928    2393088       96.000000
9422         <class 'jedi.parser.python.tree.Name              19962    1916352       96.000000
9420   <class 'jedi.parser.python.tree.PythonNode              23544    1883520       80.000000
10637           <class 'pandas.core.series.Series                102    1721291    16875.401961


                                                  object  number_of_objects       memory  mem_per_object
237                           <class '_io.BufferedWriter                  3   393744   131248.000000
11518                <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame                 24  1709443    71226.791667
12358            <class 'matplotlib.colors._ColorMapping                  1    36984    36984.000000
8946   <class 'pytz.lazy.LazySet.__new__.<locals>.Laz...                  2    66000    33000.000000
10637                  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series                102  1721291    16875.401961
235                           <class '_io.BufferedReader                  1    16560    16560.000000
11599     <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index                 11   129184    11744.000000
12719          <class 'matplotlib._cm._deprecation_datad                  2     9440     4720.000000
8945   <class 'pytz.lazy.LazyList.__new__.<locals>.La...                  2     9248     4624.000000
1594                               <class 'random.Random                  1     2560     2560.000000
```

Comment: Is it possible to get object names (to identify which objects are too large)?

Comment: Well, an object can have many names. You can still go through `globals` and check if an object from there is among the 10 largest.

Comment: What's the use of this code then if we still have to check every from hundreds of objects in globals() manually? Idea was to locate the biggest objects exactly by name, and then delete them from namespace by name to free RAM, I presume (