# Extract objects(variables) and its type from a Python script

Tags: python

I want to fetch all the variables and objects that were created in a python program with their types after it has finished execution.
Suppose I have the following Python Script :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from configparser import ConfigParser

di = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

df = pd.DataFrame(di)

config = ConfigParser()

min_max = MinMaxScaler()

new_features = []
```

**Note : This script doesn't make any sense but has just been written for demonstration.**

After this script has executed, we should get the following output. The output maybe in the form of a dictionary which can later be converted into a dataframe.

| Variables | Type |
| --- | --- |
| di | dict |
| df | DataFrame |
| config | ConfigParser |
| min_max | MinMaxScaler |
| new_features | list |

While this can be done using the IPython magic command "whos" but it has limitation that it can only be used in Jupyter or IPython cell. I want a method that is independent of any platform.

Also, I don't want to add/modify anything to this file to get the output. Any function that can solve the problem should be run externally in a different python file.

Comment: check out the python AST library, that should be the perfect solution to your current challenge

Comment: @maestro.inc Could you help me with any particular function that would solve the requirement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the list of all initialized objects and function definitions alive in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458701/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-initialized-objects-and-function-definitions-alive-in)

Comment: @paradocslover I will have to call the functions locals() or globals() in the same file to get the output. Is there any way such that I can get the required output by calling these functions externally?